# What is the difference between sql view and hive external table?

Tags: sql, hive, view, external

What is the difference between sql view and hive external table?

Comment: more details needed... a view is a select statement, an external table is table(require physical storage). So, fundamentally two diff objects.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The question is valid

althougth Koushik Roy's comment is also true, it is possible to compare a Hive external table to a sql View

Koushik Roy's comment:

> a view is a select statement, an external table is table(require physical storage). So, fundamentally two diff objects.

How I see those two objects:

SQL View -> A select statement on a physical table

HIVE External Table -> A query on a physical file

Therefore they are very similar